# What can I use instead of 'for nothing but'

Tags: british-english

What can I use instead of 'for nothing but'?

In contemporary Britain, these groups are constantly placed in the public eye for nothing but negative stories.

or is it OK in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is fine. You could also replace ***nothing but*** with *only* or *solely*.

Your example:

> In contemporary Britain, these groups are constantly placed in the
> public eye for *only* (or *solely*) negative stories.
>
> In contemporary Britain, these groups are constantly placed in the
> public eye *only* (or *solely*) for negative stories.

OD:

> [***nothing but***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nothing_but): only: *‘nothing but the best will do’*
>
> More example sentences
>
> - *‘Her health meant that if she walked out on her husband she would have nothing but the clothes she stood in.’*
> - *‘I have been looked after in an exemplary fashion and I have nothing but praise for them.’*
> - *‘Widescreen is nothing but a means to achieve presentation in the original aspect ratio.’*
> - *‘I supposed if there is nothing but noise in your life you have no choice but to deal with it.’*
> - *‘The hours were long, we were fed nothing but sandwiches, and the uniforms were awful.’*
> - *‘He held her for a very long time, in which she did nothing but simply be in his long arms, so sorry and so loving.’*
> - *‘Its nice to be able to chat with people around the world who are share nothing but the URL address in the browser.’*
> - *‘At a recent talk we gave, Ann was accused of eating nothing but scones and toasted teacakes.’*
> - *‘He's over in the kitchen area, wearing nothing but his hat and a baggy pair of Y-fronts.’*
> - *‘What he does know, however, is that working with lots of women has nothing but benefits.’*